# Not fixed Android - Proguard returned with error code 1

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, android-support-library

**I am applying progaurd protected in my app. For this I search regarding this and try to implementing them. But continuous I am getting the above error with following details.**

```
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterFactory<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar: can't find referenced class android.support.annotation.DrawableRes<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar: can't find referenced class android.support.annotation.DrawableRes<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar: can't find referenced class android.support.annotation.StringRes<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar: can't find referenced class android.support.annotation.Nullable<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$TabListener: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment<br/>

 Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment<br/>
 Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment<br/>
 Warning:android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat
 can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'int getTheme()' in class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment<br/>
 Warning: android.support.v7.internal.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener
 com.google.android.gms.internal.dg: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat<br/>
 Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment<br/>
 Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment<br/>
 Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment<br/>`enter code here`
 Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment<br/>`enter code here`

 You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.<br/>
 Warning: there were 947 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').<br/>
 Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to program class members.
 Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.<br/>
 You may need to recompile them and try again.<br/>
 Alternatively, you may have to specify the option <br/>
 '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.<br/>
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.<br/>
 at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)<br/>
 at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)<br/>
 at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)<br/>
 at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)<br/>
```

============================================================

**All the actions which I tried to resolve this issues are-**

1. Check all the compatible library only **android.support.v7** is
   used.
2. Change the compiler version **JDK1.6 to JdK1.7 and
   vice-versa**
3. Used
   **proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt and  proguard.config=proguard.cfg** separately in the
   project.properties file.
4. Enable
   **proguard.config=proguard.cfg** line in project.properties file.

## except these many others suggestion I found but no one help me to resolve my issues.

**My project.property file is**

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
Project target.
target=android-21
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
android.library.reference.1=..\\google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=../appcompat_v7
```

**And proguard-projetc.txt file is**

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb

-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; } 

-dontwarn android.support.**

-dontwarn com.google.**

-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

-libraryjars google-play-services_lib.jar

-libraryjars android.support.v7-appcompat.jar

-ignorewarnings
```

**and finally proguard.cfg file is**

```
-optimizationpasses 5

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-dontpreverify

-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field,!class/merging<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.app.Service<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference<br/>

-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService<br/>

-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.Fragment<br/>

-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService<br/>

-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService<br/>

 -keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keep class android.support.media.** { *; }

-keep interface android.support.media.** { *; }


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
} 

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
 }

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Please suggest me the solution for this I have spend lot time on this issue.

Comment: i think your appcompat is mismatch ..